# two expression at 1 time in qlikview

Tags: expression, qlikview, measure

I have 2 different expression in qlikview and i want to use these both expression at in 1 measure

first expression

```
=if(P_No_1=SubField([P No.],'-',1), 'Renew','Lost')
```

second expression

```
=If(Len(Old_Policy)=0 and Year(Today())=[Year], 'New' )
```

now i am trying to use these 2 expression at one time only .. how i do this 
any help beacuse whatever the result came from both expression i want it into 1 column ..

how i do this

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the if statements

`if(Len(Old_Policy)=0 and Year(Today())=[Year], 'New' ,
        if(P_No_1=SubField([P No.],'-',1), 'Renew','Lost'))`